# how can i open a python code using tkinter in pycharm to edit the code?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

i'm am writing a code in tkinter, and trying create a button that it's command should open a python code in pycharm application. i searched for a way to do it but all i found were ways to **run** the code, and not open it for **editing**.

this is an example button:

```
Button(self.__project_root, text=files[i].name, image=photo_image, compound=TOP).place(x=50 + 200*num, y=num_y)
```

does anyone has an advic/peace of code/link to a website explaining on it?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to edit your python code in your tkinter app?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA to open a diffrent python code in pycharm from activated tkinter app. not the same one...

Comment: Just pass the script name to `PyCharm`.

Comment: Use subprocess module. Or os.system('YOUR COMMAND TO OPEN SOMETHING'). Or something else. There are a lot of ways.

Comment: so you recommend on the os.system? i checked for many modules but all of them only offers running the code and not open it...

Comment: Why not install a system like vscode?

Comment: @AlexLiu10101 it actually doesn't matter a lot if i'll open the code on vsc ro on pycharm. i just need a way opening it in an editting application...

Comment: @schurr oh, that makes lots of sense LOL